# ImageField is not updating when update() method is used in Django Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to give a Admin the ability to update the image associated to a Product record. I have an edit class that allows the admin to update various elements of a record all of which are updating correctly except for the image fields. The problem is uploading image is working in Creating but not in Updating.

**Model**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='product_id')
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,db_column='user_id')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    unit_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    dis_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, db_column='discount_price')
    available_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    image1 = models.ImageField(db_column='product_image1', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media/images/')
    image2 = models.ImageField(db_column='product_image2', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media/images/')
    image3 = models.ImageField(db_column='product_image3', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media/images/')
```

**Serializer** :

```
from .models import Product
#Products Adding Serilaizer
class ad_products(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category','product_name','description','quantity','unit_price','dis_price','image1','image2','image3']


# Product Updating Serializer
class ad_products_update(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category','product_name','description','unit_price','dis_price','image1','image2','image3']
```

**Views** :

> POST

```
class Admin_products(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ad_products

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self,request,token):
        try:
            token1 = KnoxAuthtoken.objects.get(token_key=token)
        except:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        user = token1.user_id
        usertable = UserProfile.objects.get(id=user)
        userdata = usertable.id
        if(UserProfile.objects.filter(id=userdata, is_active='True')):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                productcategory = serializer.validated_data['category']
                productname = serializer.validated_data['product_name']
                description = serializer.validated_data['description']
                quantity = serializer.validated_data['quantity']
                unitprice = serializer.validated_data['unit_price']
                discountprice = serializer.validated_data['dis_price']
                image1 = serializer.validated_data['image1']
                image2 = serializer.validated_data['image2']
                image3 = serializer.validated_data['image3']
                if(Category.objects.filter(category_name__iexact=productcategory)):
                    tablecategory = Category.objects.get(category_name__iexact=productcategory)

                    table = Product.objects.create(product_name=productname,
                    description=description, quantity=quantity, unit_price=unitprice,
                    dis_price=discountprice,user=usertable, category=tablecategory.id, image1=image1, image2=image2, image3=image3)

                    return Response("Success", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                else:
                    data = {'message': "Category Not Found"}
                    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            data = {"message":'User is in In-Active, please Activate your account'}
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

Image is successfully uploaded to media folder and path is stored in Database.

> PUT

```
class Admin_products_update(CreateAPIView):
   serializer_class = ad_products_update

   @transaction.atomic
   def put(self,request,token,pid):
       try:
           token1 = KnoxAuthtoken.objects.get(token_key=token)
       except:
           return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
       user = token1.user_id
       usertable = UserProfile.objects.get(id=user)
       userdata = usertable.id
       if(UserProfile.objects.filter(id=userdata, is_active='True')):
           if(Product.objects.filter(user=userdata, id=pid)):
               serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
               if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                   category = serializer.validated_data['category']
                   productname = serializer.validated_data['product_name']
                   description = serializer.validated_data['description']
                   unitprice = serializer.validated_data['unit_price']
                   discountprice = serializer.validated_data['dis_price']
                   image1 = serializer.validated_data['image1']
                   image2 = serializer.validated_data['image2']
                   image3 = serializer.validated_data['image3']

                   if(Category.objects.filter(category_name__iexact=category)):
                       cat = Category.objects.get(category_name__iexact=category)
                       Product.objects.filter(id=pid, user=userdata).update(
                           category = cat.id, product_name=productname, description=description,
                           unit_price=unitprice, dis_price=discountprice,image1=image1, image2=image2, image3=image3)
                       data = {"message":'Product Details Updated successfully'}
                       return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                   else:
                       data = {'message': "Category Not Found"}
                       return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
           else:
               data = {'message' : "Product Details Not Found"} 

               return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
       else:
       data = {"message":'Account is in In-Active, please Activate your account'}
       return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

When i use Update method image path is storing in DB, but Image is not storing in Media folder.

can anyone have an idea how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

`<queryset>.update(...)` only adds kind of annotations to the *queryset* and affects only SQL query generation and does not call `model.save` method. But only `model.save` operates with model instances and calls field's `save` method which [reaches file storage](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L93). A queryset (`<model>.objects.filter().update()`) cannot not do anything with file storages.

So instead of writing an *update query* you should instantiate model instance and **save** it. DRF documentation has examples of [implementing serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) which save instances (as model instances, not direct DB update)

You use `ModelSerializer` which by default does call `instance.save` in `update` [method implementation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e7af8d662bf837e4fee844b28606cda63c0d30a9/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1006) thus it is unclear how you got to your implementation. Just follow the docs and let model.save happen.

Comment: If i use Model.save() method, it generates new row in my db and image is storing in media folder.
But my requirement is image needs to store in Media Folder and existing row needs to Update with current values

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean. Please edit your question and show full code of described functionality. Where serializer, view, queryset are involved altogether.

Comment: I have edited my question, Look into it @IvanStarostin